# Count the number of occurrences of a pattern in a string (with bash builtins only)

Tags: bash, built-in

I have a string which looks like this:

```
STRING="$PATTERN_some-stuff_$PATTERN_some-other_stuff"
```

I would like to count the number of occurences of `$PATTERN` in it, only with Bash builtin commands.

The more straightforward way of doing this I have found so far is to extract from the string only the strings that match `$PATTERN`, and then to count how many occurrences of `$PATTERN` there are in the newly created string, proceeding this way:

```
expr length "${STRING//[^$PATTERN]}" / ${#PATTERN}
```

But it only works if `$PATTERN` is a single character. I tried to use the syntax `${STRING//!(PATTERN)}"`, which would, if I understand well Bash manual, only match `$PATTERN` at the exclusion of the rest of `$STRING`, but it actually outputs nothing. So, where am I wrong ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're a bit flexible about builtins only, this is a perfect situation for `grep -o`:

```
$ STRING='$PATTERN_some-stuff_$PATTERN_some-other_stuff'
$ grep -o '$PATTERN' <<< "$STRING" | wc -l
2
```

Comment: Thans, I didn't knew this option.

Comment: `<<<word` is a Bash "here string", which is like a "here doc" *(`<<EOF\nLINES\nEOF`) but I think they can only be one line (man bash uses the word "word" to describe their content) and they have lots of expansions and substitutions performed on them as though they were a bash command.

Comment: ...for example, `<<< "$STRING"` in this answer has variable expansion and quote removal performed on it so that the contents of $STRING are what is provided on the stdin to 'grep'

Comment: The string can have newlines, it just needs to be properly quoted. Example: `nums=$(seq 10) ; grep '[2-6]' <<<"$nums"`

Answer (score 2):

One option is to replace all instances of PATTERN in STRING, subtract the length of this shortened string from the length of STRING, and then divide this by length of PATTERN. And by the way, you have flouted your bash built-in requirement by using `expr`. `expr` is a command(at least on my Ubuntu server)

```
$ declare -- PATTERN="abracadabra"
$ declare -- STRING="${PATTERN}_some-stuff_${PATTERN}_some-other_stuff"
$ echo $STRING
abracadabra_some-stuff_abracadabra_some-other_stuff
$ temp=${STRING//$PATTERN}
$ string_length_without_patterns=${#temp}
$ total_pattern_length=$((${#STRING} - $string_length_without_patterns))
$ number_of_patterns=$(($total_pattern_length/${#PATTERN}))
$ echo $number_of_patterns
2
```

Comment: This is a good idea, I will try to do this. And you are right about expr, I just misled myself. Thanks!

Comment: @doukremt, please always make sure that you accept/voteup the answer if you got the solution. Points are like motivation for all who are actively working in SO.

Comment: I would like to, but I don't have enough reputation to do this. I will do this as soon as I can.